# Mongodb using dynamic fields with $not

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I programming in react, mongodb, nodejs and expressjs. I have a problem that I cannot solve. I would like to use dynamic fields from $not on the server. For example, the server gets the column name from the front and it is supposed to return the number of documents where the text is different from an empty string, i.e. `''`. I've tried to do something like this(code below), but it doesn't help.

```
const query = {};
query[type] = { $not: '' };
User.countDocuments(query, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
});
```

Comment: Where is the value you're trying to compare with the `$not` ?

Comment: it doesn't work when i do it this way: const query = {
  $not: {
   type: ''
  }
 };

Comment: Can you include the desired query you want to build dynamically? It's unclear to me what the field and what the value is..

Comment: This query is appended, it wants to extract a count of elements, where type (this is the column name given dynamically) where the value is equal to the empty string.

Comment: Ok, think I got it now, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, you probably were looking for `$ne` instead of `$not`. So changing it to

```
const query = {};
query[type] = { $ne: '' };
```

should fix the issue. This would find all documents where the dynamic `type` field does not equal `''`. If you want to do the inverse, i.e. find all documents where the dynamic field equals an empty string, change it to:

```
query[type] = { $eq: '' };
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.